# What if I am not the right fit in a certain lab as a postdoc?

Tags: research-process, postdocs

Almost everything is in the title of my question. More precisely, what if my advisor wants me to do research by using methods in a field that is not my field of expertise/interest?

Thanks!

Comment: Your options would seem to be expanding your expertise, or switching to another lab.

Comment: Expanding your expertise is the whole point of doing a postdoc in the first place; you might as well be thankful for this opportunity. Lack of interest is another story. In this case, switching the lab would be an option - but keep in mind that a future employer might be curious what made you select the current lab.

Comment: Can you please add some more information?  Right now it's difficult to advise, especially because you are combining expertise and interest.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that your postdoc advisor is the one that was directly responsible for your hiring. In such cases, she is presumably well aware of your skill set and former training, Presuming that she has not intentionally set you up to fail (a reasonable assumption, given her investment of time and money in you, and the potential damage to her reputation and your career), you should look on this as an opportunity to demonstrate that your PhD is well-earned. After all, the goal of a PhD is to certify that you are capable of learning a new discipline and making a demonstrable contribution to the state of knowledge in the field. Being put into a project outside your "comfort zone" is a perfect way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. The point is that first changing discipline would take me a while to start make my contribution and second I do not want to do that; I graduated for my bachelor, master, and Ph.D. on my discipline, this's what I love. To be clear, we're talking about changing discipline and not just topic, that is what I expected. At the end of the day in research what counts more should be passion and especially training and those do not come in one year, isn't it?